# Why is unbiased covariance estimator improtant regarding statistical estimation and real-world application?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

For example, we want to estimate the covariance matrix from a given set of data points. We can derive an unbiased estimator. However, we can still derive an estimator by minimizing information loss in the data.

Then, why is unbiased covariance estimator important regarding statistical estimation and real-world application?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "minimizing information loss"? If you have a parametrized family of distributions you can use maximum likelihood, which generally would be biased for this sort of thing but might perform slightly better in some ways that unbiased estimators. (Certainly in the one-dimensional case it does if you're using squared-error loss. But only slightly.) I wouldn't attach any great importance to unbiasedness in this context.

Comment: The information means the Entropy http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-06/lectures/entropy/entropy.pdf ,  and we hope that we can keep entropy in the data as much as possible when deriving the estimator. This is almost equivalent to the maximum likelihood http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shashua/papers/class3-ML-MaxEnt.pdf. As you said, biased estimator can perform slightly better than unbiased, could you please show why we need unbiased in the perspective of the theory analysis and practical application? Please

Comment: Without further context I know of no reason why unbiasedness is needed.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think we need unbiasedness because it allows the estimator to converge the target covariance after receiving more data samples.

Comment: You don't need unbiasedness for that. The MLE also converges to the population covariance.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks. But MLE can get consistent estimator for other estimation task regardless of the covariance?

Comment: Yes. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Always?

Comment: By "always", if you mean in all situations in which maximum likelihood can be applied, including things that are not about estimating covariances, then I don't think so. But I think it will always work for estimating a population covariance matrix.